# jQuery $.ajax is not triggering anything to happen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a text box and whenever a user enters a message and clicks on send, the ajax should be activated and what's on insertMessage.php should get triggered. However, whenever i click on send it doesn't work. here is my chatbox.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "events");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$user=$_SESSION['userid'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`='$user'";
$res= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$user=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            
                <p>Hi <?php echo $user["FullName"]; ?></p>
                <input type="text" id="fromUser" value=<?php echo $user["Email"]; ?> hidden />
            <p>Send Message To:</p>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    $msgs=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users");
                    while($msg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($msgs))
                    {
                        echo '<li><a href="?toUser='.$msg['Email'].'">'.$msg["FullName"].'</a></li>';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
            <a href="index.php"><--Back</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title"><?php 
                        if(isset($_GET["toUser"]))
                        {
                            $user=$_GET["toUser"];
                            $email=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$user'");
                            $emails=mysqli_fetch_assoc($email);
                            echo '<input type="text" value='.$user.' id="toUser" hidden/>';
                            echo $emails["Email"];
                        }
                        else{
                        
                            $email=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users");
                            $emails=mysqli_fetch_assoc($email);
                            $_SESSION['toUser']=$emails['Email'];
                            echo '<input type="text" value='.$_SESSION['toUser'].' id="toUser" hidden/>';
                            echo $emails["Email"];
                        }
                    ?></h5>
                </div>
            <div class="model-body" id="msgBody" style="height:400px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
            <?php
            if(isset($_GET["toUser"]))
            {
                $chats=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE (`Receiver`='".$_SESSION["userid"]."' AND `Sender`='".$_GET["toUser"]."') OR  (`Receiver`='".$_GET["toUser"]."' AND `Sender`='".$_SESSION["userid"]."')");
                
            }
            else{
            $chats=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE (`Sender`='".$_SESSION["userid"]."' AND `Receiver`='".$_GET["toUser"]."') OR  (`Sender`='".$_GET["toUser"]."' AND `Receiver`='".$_SESSION["userid"]."')");
                    
            }
            while($chat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($chats))
            {
                if($chat["Sender"]==$_SESSION["userid"])
                {
                    echo "<div style='text-align:right;'>
                        <p style='background-color:lightblue; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block; padding:5px; border-radius:10px; max-width:70%;'>
                        ".$chat["Message"]."</p>
                    </div>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<div style='text-align:left;'>
                        <p style='background-color:yellow; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block; padding:5px; border-radius:10px; max-width:70%;'>
                        ".$chat["Message"]."</p>
                    </div>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </div>
            <div class="model-footer">
            
            <textarea id="message" class="form-control" style="height:43px;max-width:80%;float:left;">
            </textarea>
            
            <button id="send" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:70%;float:left;">Send</button>
            
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#send').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                   url:"insertMessage.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{
                        fromUser: $("#fromUser").val();
                        toUser:$("#toUser").val();
                        message:$("#message").val();
                    },
                    dataType:"text",
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#message").val("");
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        });

</script>
</html>
```

and here is my insertMessage.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "events");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$fromUser=$_POST["fromUser"];
$toUser=$_POST["toUser"];
$message=$_POST["message"];

$output="";

$sql="INSERT INTO `message`(`Sender`, `Receiver`, `Message`) VALUES ('$fromUser','$toUser','$message')";
if($connect->query($sql)){
    $output.="";
}
else{
    $output.="Error. Please Try Again.";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

I don't know what to do i tried to find the issue so much but I couldn't. I am new to ajax so I don't know..

Comment: HI, check your browser console is there any error ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your exact problem is but there is one issue in your jQuery code, it takes an object as a value of data, like below :

```js
data: {
    fromUser: $("#fromUser").val(),
    toUser: $("#toUser").val(),
    message: $("#message").val()
  },
  dataType: "text",
```

Replace your semicolon (;) with a comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

Put all your form elements inside a `<form>` in order to receive a data from your `$_POST`.

```
<form method="post" action="insertMessage.php">
  /* your form elements here */
</form>
```

Don't forget to include `method="post"` in your form element, put `name="fieldName"` on your input elements (text, button, textarea) and a submit button.

Comment: it doesn't go to the insertMessage.php.. it just refreshes the page :/

Comment: Sorry @CheveeFerrer, but, OP wants to use AJAX. Your solution does not consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` seems to have issues:

So, please change:

```
 data:{
                        fromUser: $("#fromUser").val();
                        toUser:$("#toUser").val();
                        message:$("#message").val();
                    },
```

To:

```
 data:{
                        fromUser: $("#fromUser").val(),
                        toUser:$("#toUser").val(),
                        message:$("#message").val()
                    },
```

**Explanation:**
Semi colons(`;`)are for closing a statement.

And the `fromUser` and others are properties of object `data`. So, they should be comma separated and it is one statement.

Also, as a suggestion:

`<input type="text" id="fromUser" value=<?php echo $user["Email"]; ?> hidden />`

The above field definition should have double quotes(`""`) around `value`.
It creates issues(without semi-colons) when there are spaces in our `value`.

And `hidden` makes no meaning at all with above, is it of `type="hidden"` or is it `class="hidden"`?